# Setting display to reduce migraines, what does nomodeset and fbdev mean? and how to set them?

Tags: display, intel-graphics, vga, nomodeset

In a forum about migraines and computer displays, i've found these instructions:"and try nomodeset for intel kernel module i915 and the fbdev video driver. It's basically the same thing as Standard VGA in Windows 7."

What does those mean ? how do i achieve them in ubuntu ?

Comment: Those instructions seem like nonsense. You'll get a wrong resolution with nomodset, and an inferior driver with fbdev. How are they related to mirgraines is unclear. Search for those options if you want to know what they are.

Comment: I haven't really dug deeply into the technical causes - i'm more interested in solutions. It's from a community of sufferers , who've noticed, both on windows and linux , that sometimes driver updates cause problems(. so they've tried using standard VGA drivers(on windows), and it helped. How do you get that on linux ? they say fbdev, nomodeset.